# Which tests should I use for my experiment

Tags: hypothesis-testing, repeated-measures, experiment-design

For each participant in my trial I have 35 parameters ($P_1,\ldots,P_{35}$), each measured at 4 different time points. Furthermore, the participants are partitioned into two groups $A$ and $B$, each containing approximately 15 participants each.

Now I want to obtain the following:

- For each parameter $P_i$ I want to know whether there is a significant difference between any of its four time measurements. If there is a significant difference, I want to know between which time points this difference is present.
- For both groups $A$ and $B$ and for each parameter $P_i$, I want to know whether there is a significant difference between any of its four time measurements. If there is a significant difference, I want to know between which time points this difference is present.
- For each individual time point $t$, I want to know for each parameter $P_i$ whether there is a significant difference for groups $A$ and $B$ for this $P_i$ measured at time $t$.

Assuming that my data is nearly normally distributed, but not normally distributed, I would like some information on which tests I have to perform to obtain an answer on these questions.

For the first two items, I already compared, for each individual parameter, every two of its time points by using the Wilcoxon signed-rank test. For the last item, I already used the Mann-Whitney U test. However, I was told that using the same parameter 16 times leads to a very heavy correction, which makes it impossible to find significant differences.